# "Add More" button resetting input fields in the browser

Tags: javascript, html

I need JavaScript to create a new HTML input field every time the "add more" button is clicked. To accomplish this, I wrote this code:

```
function addTime(){

`let scheduler = document.getElementById("schedule").innerHTML;` 

`document.getElementById("moreTime").innerHTML = scheduler;`
}
```

The `("schedule")` ID is the `div` that holds the input fields I need and I added an `"onclick"` to the "add more" button that calls the addTime function when the button is clicked and it works!

The problem is that every time the button is clicked in the web browser, it creates new input fields, but it resets the values from the previous input fields that are created by clicking the button while the original HTML input element that shows up in the browser is untouched. I've tried changing the button from the `<button></button>` tag, to the `<input>` tag. I've tried using an event listener both in the function and when the function is called. The button still works under all of these conditions, but it still resets the values, so, I am assuming it has something to do with the code in the function, not the HTML code.

Why is it doing this and how do I get JavaScript to create new input fields when the button is clicked AND store the values of the previously created input fields when the button is clicked again?

Thanks a lot in advance for your help!

Oh! I should probably add that the input field is an HTML "time" that looks like 00:00 am/pm. The default for the field in the web browser is -- : -- -- with a little clock to add the desired time and time of day.

EDIT: Here is the HTML code for the input fields --

```
<div id = "schedule">
                    <p>From: </p> <input id = "start" type = "time" value = "" > 
                    <p id = "to"> To: </p><input id = "end" type = "time" value = ""> 
        
<!--- give the user the option to add more than one schedule item-->
                    <div id = "moreTime"> </div>
                 </div>
        
                <input type = "button" onclick = "addTime()" value = "add schedule"/>
```

Comment: You have `.innerHTML = scheduler;`, but if you want to *add* buttons, not replace everything that existed previously, don't you want something like `.innerHTML += scheduler;` ?

Comment: Hi CP! As I stated, I am new to this... like really new! So, I didn't know that you could += an .innerHTML. However, I did read something that says that using that could present security risks. Does that apply in this case? Do you know? Thank you so much for your help! Also, I will try the += and see what happens!

Comment: It won't fix the problem, but adding to the existing HTML instead of completely replacing the HTML sounds like a start for your objective. Yes, using `innerHTML` with untrusted input is unsafe.

Comment: CP... I tried the +=,  it still reset the values when the button was clicked, but it also doubled the amount of input fields created! That's not what I want. I don't want to add more buttons, I want the "add more" button to create a new input field every time it is clicked while not resetting the values of the previous fields.

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions

Comment: Your first paragraph is irrelevant to the question. Please do not roll it back to re-add it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```js
let schedule = document.getElementById("schedule");
let html = schedule.innerHTML;

function addTime() {
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.innerHTML = html;
  schedule.appendChild(div.firstElementChild);
}
```

```html
<div id="schedule">
  <div class="times">
    <p>From: </p> <input id="start" type="time" value="">
    <p id="to"> To: </p><input id="end" type="time" value="">
  </div>
</div>

<input type="button" onclick="addTime()" value="add schedule" />
```

The issue was that `#moreTime` kept getting overwitten after clicking the button more than once. To make it work as many times as needed, copy the HTML to be duplicated before the user has added any values. This can then be converted to a node and appended with each button click.